# Is there a way to select elements of a series using a range in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column titled "delta pI" in my dataframe and I want to get rid of everything where 0.5> delta pI value>-0.5. How should I do so using pandas?

```
df2 = df[  (df['delta pI'] > -0.5) & (df['delta pI'] < 0.5))
& (df['delta Size'] <= -30) | (df['delta Size'] >= 30)
         & (df['Average 10G_Fn']!=1)]
```

Comment: By 'everything' do you mean drop all rows where delta pi is between 0.5 and -0.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to return a Series of booleans and use it to slice the rows to keep:

```py
df[~df['delta pI'].between(-0.5, 0.5)]
```